# Symfony 2.3 / FOSUserBundle: Redirect to login page even if route is not matched

Tags: symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

I installed the FOSUserBundle for Symfony 2.3.x because I want to create a "secure" area for which the user needs to be logged in.

I setup `security.yml` like shown below:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This works just fine. I want all requests for `/admin/*` to be redirected to the login page if the user is not logged in, even when the route is not matched.

In the current setup, routes that match are redirected to the login page. When a route is not matched, an error page is shown.

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to how I can achieve the functionality as stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no real simple symfony security solution (AFAIK) i've done the following to get the wanted functionality.

**Step 1: Greedy route**
In the services.yml i've added a greedy route to the bottom of the file (so it gets read last). This greedy route mimics the existence of the route (even if it doesn't actually exist). This route makes sure that all requests from /admin (except for /admin/login, /admin/login_check and /admin/logout) are redirected to a custom redirect controller.

This route is placed to the bottom of the routing.yml file, so if there is a route that matches an existing route, it will not get redirected to the RedirectController, but to the controller specific to that route.

```
admin:
pattern: /admin/{var}
requirements:
    var: "^(?!(login|login_check|logout)$).*"
defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Redirect:index }
```

**Step 2**
Make sure that routes that are required for the login are available for the IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY (whitelist) in security.yml.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: "^/admin", roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**Step 3**
Since non-existing routes are always matched to the greedy pattern from step 1, I can redirect everything to a custom 404 page when the user is logged in. This is what I am doing in my RedirectController.

This method works for me, but it's not the most graceful way. Suppose I place routes after the greedy route from, they will never be matched. This is bad for testability.

If anyone has a better idea, please share :)

*So far, special thanks to enigma, I came to this solution from the ideas in your comment.*

Answer (score 2):

This configuration should work for you:

```
firewalls:
      admin:
            pattern:  /admin(.*)
            context:  user
            form_login:
                 provider:       fos_userbundle
                 login_path:     /admin/login
                 use_forward:    false
                 check_path:     /admin/login_check
                 failure_path:   null
```

Comment: Thank you for your response enigma! This seems to get me a bit closer to what I want, but with this configuration I experience two issues as far as I can see.

1. Everything from /admin/test gets redirected to the login form, but if there's one more url part (e.g. /admin/test/test2), then it doesn't redirect to the login form anymore and gives a route not found exception.

2. When i do get redirected to /admin/login I get stuck in a loop, and I am not yet sure why.

Comment: I've solved the issue with the redirect loop. I found out I hadn't correctly overwritten the standard FOSUserBundle login routes. I was routing to /admin/login but login was located at /login. The one problem that remains though (and I am still unable to solve) is why routing for /admin/test redirects correctly to the login form, while /admin/test/another_test doesn't.

Comment: At the moment I do not see a simple solution, either. I guess it has nothing to do with the pattern matching and firewall, but with routing. You could make your own RedirectController, that you could configure in a routing.yml file to be called on the prefix `/admin`, like the Symfony FrameworkBundle RedirectController. The mentioned controller could be used to inherit the current behavior.